# How to Dynamically Label my Buttons Based on Database Query using Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to label my button dynamically based on the database results. So in this case the button would be labeled '23'

Database

| id |  number |

| 1 |  23

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql as mdb

from tkinter import ttk


#functions
def functionHolder():
    print("do nothing function holder")


root = Tk()
dbi = mdb.connect("localhost",port=3306, user="access", passwd="***", db="index_db" )
cursor = dbi.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT number FROM caution_elements WHERE id = 1 """)
dbi.commit()
data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
dbi.close()

result =str("%s " % data)



 varButt = Button(root,textvariable=data, command=functionHolder)
 varButt.pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

Button should be labeled [23] I currently get a blank button and no errors

Comment: you don't need `str("%s " % data)` to convert to string - use `str(data)` or `"%s " % data` if you need space at the end.

Comment: `textvariable=` expects special class `tkinter.StringVar()`. If you have your numer in `result` then use `text=result` or even `text=data`

Comment: What do you mean by "labeled [23]"? Do you mean the text on the button?

Comment: result =str(data)

varButt = Button(root,text=result, command=functionHolder)
varButt.pack()

Worked!!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A `textvariable` option of tkinter widgets require special variable classes such as `StringVar`, `BooleanVar` or `IntVar`. Their values can be accessed using `get` method and their values can be changed using `set` as in:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

data = tk.StringVar()
data.set("This")

def change():
    if data.get() == "This":
        data.set("That")
    else:
        data.set("This")

tk.Label(root, textvariable=data).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Change", command=change).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you are [not sure about using class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334885/why-would-we-use-class-variables-stringvar-intvar-booleanvar) another example without them would be:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

data = "This"

def change():
    global data
    if data == "This":
        data = "That"
        a_label['text'] = data
    else:
        data = "This"
        a_label.config(text=data)


a_label = tk.Label(root, text=data)
a_label.pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Change", command=change).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Both of the code pieces do the same thing except that when you change `data`'s value, in the first example you're also changing text displayed by the label, and in the second example you need to explicitly update `a_label`'s text option.

---

Also note that you can use `a_widget.config(option=value)`, `a_widget.configure(option=value)`, `a_widget['option'] = value` interchangeably given that you're modifying *only one* option.

Comment: Further, when you tie the Label text to a StringVar() like *data*, when you programmatically update the StringVar value with a call to the `set()` method `data.set('hello')`, you will see the text on the Button magically change, too. That's part of the beauty of the event-driven GUI world of Tkinter.  Once configured properly, you can make a change in one place, and it can propagate throughout your GUI.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense.