# Label text changing when dictionary is updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to coding and i've been messing around with tkinter.

My labels have text, that is supposed to change when the dictionary values are updated.

An example of my code:

```
    def setit(point, adic,number):
         adic[point] = adic[point]+number

    dict={'a':4,'b':8,'c':3}
    aa=Label(root,text=dict['a']).pack()
    bb=Label(root,text=dict['b']).pack()
    cc=Label(root,text=dict['c']).pack()
    Button(command=setit('a',dict,3)).pack()
```

When the button is pressed i want both the dictionary and the appropriate Label to update. How would you do that? Preferably without OOP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two problems in your code sample:

1) `.pack()` returns `None`, so when you do `aa=Label(root,text=dict['a']).pack()`, you store `None` in the variable `aa`, not the label. You should do:

```
aa = Label(root,text=dict['a'])
aa.pack()
```

2) The `command` option of a button takes a function as argument but you do `command=setit('a',dict,3)` so you execute the function at the button creation. To pass a function with arguments to a button command, you can use a `lambda`:

```
Button(command=lambda: setit('a',dict,3))
```

Then, to update the label when the value in the dictionary is changed, you can store your labels in a dictionary with the same keys and change the text of the appropriate label with `label.configure(text='new value')`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def setit(point, adic, label_dic, number):
     adic[point] = adic[point] + number  # change the value in the dictionary
     label_dic[point].configure(text=adic[point])  # update the label

root = tk.Tk()

dic = {'a': 4, 'b': 8, 'c': 3}
# make a dictionary of labels with keys matching the ones of dic
labels = {key: tk.Label(root, text=dic[key]) for key in dic}
# display the labels
for label in labels.values():
    label.pack()

tk.Button(command=lambda: setit('a', dic, labels, 3)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instead of specifying the text value.  That looks like:

```
d={'a':StringVar(),'b':StringVar(),'c':StringVar()}
aa=Label(root,textvariable=d['a'])
bb=Label(root,textvariable=d['b'])
cc=Label(root,textvariable=d['c'])

aa.pack()
bb.pack()
cc.pack()
```

And then whenever you want to change the label, you can do

```
d['a'].set("new text!")
```

See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) for more info on labels.

Note: `dict` is a reserved word in python, so it's best to not use that as the name of your variable. Same goes for `str`, `int`, etc.

Comment: in this example, `aa`, `bb`, and `cc` will all be `None`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, good point.  I just mindlessly copied that part of OP's code because it wasn't directly related to his question about changing label values.

Comment: I'd also see, [Why would we use a variable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47334885/7032856).