# Returning PY_VARxxx instead of expected string

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently creating a GUI in order to turn a lot of individual instruments into one complete system. In `def smuSelect(self)` I create a list `self.smuChoices` I can use to call individual choices such as `smuChoices[0]` and it will return `"2410(1)"`.

Once I call `def checkBoxSetup` it returns `PY_VARxxx`.  I've tried searching the different forums and everything. I've seen mentions using the `.get()` which just gives me the state of the individual choice. The reason I want the actual string itself is I would like to use it in `def testSetup(self)` for the user to assign specific names to the individual machine, for example, `2410 = Gate`.

My initial attempt was to create another variable `smuChoice2` but I believe this is still changing the original list `self.smuChoices`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from tkinter import ttk


def checkBoxSetup(smuChoice2): #TK.INTVAR() IS CHANGING NAME OF SMUS NEED TO CREATE ANOTHER INSTANCE OF SELF.SMUCHOICES

    for val, SMU in enumerate(smuChoice2):

        smuChoice2[val] = tk.IntVar()
        b = tk.Checkbutton(smuSelection,text=SMU,variable=smuChoice2[val])
        b.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SMU Selection")


"""
    Selects the specific SMUs that are going to be used, only allow amount up to chosen terminals.
    --> If only allow 590 if CV is picked, also only allow use of low voltage SMU (maybe dim options that aren't available)
    --> Clear Checkboxes once complete
    --> change checkbox selection method
"""
smuChoices = [
            "2410(1)",
            "2410(2)",
            "6430",
            "590 (CV)",
            "2400",
            "2420"
            ]
smuChoice2 = smuChoices
smuSelection = ttk.Frame(root)

selectInstruct = tk.Label(smuSelection,text="Choose SMUs").grid()
    print(smuChoices[0])    #Accessing list prior to checkboxsetup resulting in 2410(1)

checkBoxSetup(smuChoice2)

print(smuChoices[0])    #Accessing list after check box setup resulting in PY_VAR376
variableSMUs = tk.StringVar()

w7_Button = tk.Button(smuSelection,text="Enter").grid()

w8_Button = tk.Button(smuSelection,text="Setup Window").grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all getting `PY_VARXX` instead of what's in a variable class indicates the lack of `get()`.

replace:

```
print(self.smuChoices[0])
```

with:

```
print(self.smuChoices[0].get())
```

Secondly, if you want to display the value of a variable class on a `label`, `button`, etc. you could rather just use the `textvariable` option by simply assigning the variable class to it.

Replace:

```
tk.Label(self.smuName,text=SMU).grid()
```

with:

```
tk.Label(self.smuName, textvariable=self.smuChoices[val]).grid()
```

---

Your question is still a bit unclear to me but I will try to provide an answer to the best of my understanding.

As I understand it, you're trying to create a set of `Checkbutton`s for a given list of items. Below is an example of a method that takes `items` as an argument and returns a dictionary of checkboxes that have `root` as their parent:

```
import tkinter as tk

def dict_of_cbs(iterable, parent):
    if iterable:
        dict_of_cbs = dict()
        for item in iterable:
            dict_of_cbs[item] = tk.Checkbutton(parent)
            dict_of_cbs[item]['text'] = item
            dict_of_cbs[item].pack()            # it's probably a better idea to manage
                                                # geometry in the same place  wherever
                                                # the parent is customizing its
                                                # children's layout
    return dict_of_cbs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    items = ("These", "are", "some", "items.")
    my_checkboxes = dict_of_cbs(items, root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Additionally note that I haven't used any variable classes (`BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar` or `StringVar`) as [they seem to be redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47334885/7032856) in this particular case.

Comment: The only thing the .get() method returns is a 1 or a 0 indicating whether or not the box is checked or not, I understand this.  My problem lies in trying to get the actual machine name from the list.  I believe something fundamentally (possibly when calling tk.IntVar() in def checkBoxSetup) is changing in def checkBoxSetup because prior to calling that I can get the smu name by saying self.smuChoices[0] without using .get().  I tried using the .get() function previously and all it returns is the state of the checkbox.  Apologies for saying it worked when in fact it didn't

Comment: @Dj1612 If only you were able to create a [mcve], it would've been much easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I didn't realize there was an actual definition for Minimal, complete and Verifiable example.  I thought it was just shorten the code to the necessary definitions, this is my first post I apologize.  Either way I think my edited code satisfies the requirements

Comment: @Dj1612 Pleas re-verify your code, while it may have lost the redundant parts, it still appears that it has some mistakes. Please copy the exact code you've provided while verifying.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing my list, **smuChoices**, to a dictionary then modifying

```
def checkBoxSetup(smuChoice2): 

 for val, SMU in enumerate(smuChoice2):
     smuChoice2[val] = tk.IntVar()
     b = tk.Checkbutton(smuSelection,text=SMU,variable=smuChoice2[val])
     b.grid()
```

to

```
def checkBoxSetup(self): 
   for i in self.smuChoices:
       self.smuChoices[i] = tk.IntVar()
       b = tk.Checkbutton(self.smuSelection,text=i,variable=self.smuChoices[i])
       b.grid()
```

Previously I was replacing the variable with what I'm guessing is some identifier that tkinter uses to store the state which is why I was getting PYxxx.