# Why are the two tkinter entries using the same number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import *

coord1 = "0,0"
coord2 = "0,0"
EQ = "y = mx + b"


def tkinter_window():
    global coord1Entry
    global coord2Entry
    global coord1
    global coord

    tk = Tk()

    tk.title("Math Graph")

    #create
    font1 = tkFont.Font(family="Source Code Pro", size=16)
    font2 = tkFont.Font(family="Source Code Pro", size=10)

    coord1Label = Label(tk, text='X coordinate 1:\n( "x,y", no parentheses )', font=font1)
    coord2Label = Label(tk, text='Y coordinate 2:\n( "x,y", no parentheses )', font=font1)
```

This is the part where i define the two entries that seem to use the same numbers:

```
    coord1Entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=coord1)
    coord2Entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=coord2)
```

So the problem is, when i run the program they show nothing, as usual. But as soon as i enter one character in one of the entries, they both show the character(s). I don't understand why, they use different variables? Can someone help me?

```
    coordButton = Button(tk, text="Done! (use coordinates)", font=font1)


    equationLabel = Label(tk, text="Equation: y =", font=font1)
    equationEntry = Entry(tk, textvariable=EQ, font=font1)
    equationButton = Button(tk, text="Done! (use equation)", font=font1)

    iwantanswersCheckbox = Checkbutton(tk, text="I want m, x, b, intercept and x-intercept", font=font1)
    iwantgraphCheckbox = Checkbutton(tk, text="I want a graph", font=font1)
    info1Label = Label(tk, text="***Both boxes may be checked***", font=font2)


    #pack
    coord1Label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    coord2Label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)

    coord1Entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    coord2Entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    coordButton.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=15)


    equationLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    equationEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    equationButton.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=15)

    iwantanswersCheckbox.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    iwantgraphCheckbox.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)
    info1Label.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

    os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
    tk.mainloop()

tkinter_window()

def matplotlib_window():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    coordX[0] = Xcoord1Entry.get()
    coordX[1] = Xcoord2Entry.get()
    coordY[0] = Ycoord1Entry.get()
    coordY[1] = Ycoord2Entry.get()
    plt.plot(coordX, coordY)
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.show()
```

Main area of code where the problem should be (as requested):

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import *

coord1 = "0,0"
coord2 = "0,0"


def tkinter_window():
    global coord1Entry
    global coord2Entry
    global coord1
    global coord

    tk = Tk()

    tk.title("Math Graph")

    #create
    font1 = tkFont.Font(family="Source Code Pro", size=16)
    font2 = tkFont.Font(family="Source Code Pro", size=10)

    coord1Label = Label(tk, text='X coordinate 1:\n( "x,y", no parentheses )', font=font1)
    coord2Label = Label(tk, text='Y coordinate 2:\n( "x,y", no parentheses )', font=font1)

    coord1Entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=coord1)
    coord2Entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=coord2)


    #pack
    coord1Label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    coord2Label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)

    coord1Entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    coord2Entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


    tk.mainloop()

tkinter_window()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to the problem you're having as opposed to sliced code pieces.

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47334885/7032856) for deciding when to use `textvariable` option.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are using identical strings for the `textvariable` option when you need to be using two different instances of one of the [special tkinter variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) (`StringVar`, etc)

By the way, you almost never need to use `textvariable`. My advice is to omit it since you're clearly not using it.

---

This happens because the widget is just a thin wrapper around a widget implemented in an embedded Tcl interpreter. The string value of the `textvariable` option is treated as a global variable name in the embedded Tcl interpreter. Since both strings are the same, they become the same variable within the tcl interpreter (and yes, `"0.0"` is perfectly valid as a tcl variable).

This behavior is actually why `textvariable` can be such a powerful tool -- you can link two or more widgets together so that when a value changes in one, it is immediately reflected in the other. Plus, it is possible to set traces on these variables so that you can get a callback when the variable is read, written, or unset.

However, this is much more useful when coding in Tcl, since in Tcl a `textvariable` can be a normal Tcl variable. In tkinter, it must be a special type of object -- an instance of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar`, or `BooleanVar` -- so you can't use it with ordinary variables.

Comment: K, thanks, i don't really understand how that connected the two entries together but i replaced the "o,o"'s by "".

Comment: I found this to be an odd behavior, what's the fundamental reason this happens?

Comment: @Nae: I've updated my answer to try to briefly describe what is happening.

Comment: @Cedric: if you replace `"0.0"` with `""`, you might as well not use `textvariable` at all. The _only_ reason to use `textvariable` is if you want to access it later. Otherwise it serves no purpose whatsoever

Comment: The reason to use `textvariable` is so you can update it later. It's all part of what is effectively Tk's native [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) system. Tkinter code doesn't usually take good advantage of it (or it would use the `trace` method of `StringVar` more).

Comment: True, but since you can update the widgets without the `textvariable`, in tkinter it's fairly useless unless you're going to add a trace or unless you explicitly want to tie two or more widgets together.