# Why is having identical str(object)s as textvariable option to widgets make their texts synchronized?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48352058/7032856) made me wonder, what is exactly going on in the code below?

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyDot():
    def __str__(self):
        return "."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_dot = MyDot()
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=root).pack()
    tk.Label(root, textvariable=my_dot).pack()
    tk.Button(root, textvariable=".").pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Why is having identical `str(object)`s, as `textvariable` option to widgets make their texts synchronized?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit scary if they *didn't* share the same content?

Comment: @PeterLewerin Well, I updated the mcve to better reflect my surprize.

Comment: The widgets are guaranteed to have the same contents as the variable, and they share the same variable. How could they have different contents?

Comment: @PeterLewerin They don't share the _same variable_ per se as far as python is concerned. They just happen to have the same _string_, which is apparently the same variable in _Tcl_.

Comment: Now I see your confusion, I think. Python apparently delegates all or most of what Tk does to a Tcl interpreter, so the string becomes the name of a variable that lives in that interpreter's memory but is invisible and unreachable from Python. (In Tcl/Tk it is common practice to synchronize widgets this way.) On the Python side, this interaction is of course less obvious as the variable doesn't exist as a Python variable. Sorry for misunderstanding your question.