# Python Entry box takes text input in multiple Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

Im making a GUI application where I have 4 Entry section and if I enter text in one Entry box all Entry box are taking data. How do I code such that only on clicking over Entry box it should take input respectively...

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def time():
 t1h=int(Ihr.get())
 t1m=int(Imin.get())
 t2h=int(Ohr.get())
 t2m=int(Omin.get())

app = Tk()
app.title("VM")
app.geometry("150x210")
app.resizable(0,0)    

note = Label(app, text="Clock IN Time :")
note.place(x=10, y=10)
Ihr = Entry(app,text="...")
Ihr.place(x=10, y=30,width="30")
Ihr.focus()
note = Label(app, text="::")
note.place(x=43, y=30)
Imin = Entry(app,text="...")
Imin.place(x=60, y=30,width="30")
note = Label(app, text="(hr)")
note.place(x=12, y=50)
note = Label(app, text="(min)")
note.place(x=58, y=50)
```

Comment: [Why is having identical str(object)s as textvariable option to widgets make their texts synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48352341/7032856)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ihr = Entry(app,text="...")
```

```
Imin = Entry(app,text="...")
```

I suspect the problem is on these two lines, in particular the `text` keyword arguments. At first glance I don't see the behavior of `text` [documented](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) [anywhere](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm), but I'm guessing they behave something like the `textvariable` argument. Since they both point to the same "..." object, changing one Entry will change the other.

Don't use the `text` argument to set the text of Entries. Use the `.insert` method instead.

```
Ihr = Entry(app)
Ihr.insert(0, "...")
```

```
Imin = Entry(app)
Imin.insert(0, "...")
```

---

Update:

Bryan Oakley confirms that the `text` and `textvariable` keyword arguments have the same effect. Generally, you should not pass a string object to these arguments; a StringVar is most conventional. You may be interested in using StringVars here, since you can use their `.set` method to set the contents of the Entry objects, without having to use the arguably more complicated `.insert` method.

```
Ihr_var = StringVar()
Ihr_var.set("...")
Ihr = Entry(app,text=Ihr_var)
```

```
Imin_var = StringVar()
Imin_var.set("...")
Imin = Entry(app,text=Imin_var)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got what was needed.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I think we've had this conversation before :-D but I couldn't remember what our conclusion was the last time, hence my equivocal tone above.

Comment: All tkinter options can be specified with an abbreviation, as long as it's unambiguous. For example, `back` instead of `background`, `wi` instead of `width`, etc. You can't use `b` for `borderwidth` since it's ambiguous (tkinter can't tell if you meant `borderwidth` or `background`).