# StringVar() / IntVar() not returning the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button, tkinter-entry

Please see that, I had referred to similar related answers too on this topics

1) What are the cases, that StringVar() / IntVar() would return blank / 0 value resp.?

2) Below is my smaller part of code applied to one of the functionalities in my app. Please do tell me what am I missing in my code to retrieve the expected output.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack()
        Label(self,text="Choose timer options:").pack()
        self.delayvar = IntVar()
        self.delayradio1 = Radiobutton(self,text="Hours",variable=self.delayvar,value=1,command=self.delayfunc)
        self.delayradio1.pack()
        self.delayradio2 = Radiobutton(self,text="Minutes",variable=self.delayvar,value=2,command=self.delayfunc)
        self.delayradio2.pack()
        self.delayradio3 = Radiobutton(self,text="Seconds",variable=self.delayvar,value=3,command=self.delayfunc)
        self.delayradio3.pack()

    def delayfunc(self):
        self.delayvarvalue = self.delayvar.get()
        self.delayentryvar = StringVar()    # or IntVar()
        self.delayent = Entry(self,textvariable=self.delayentryvar)
        self.delayent.pack()
        if self.delayvarvalue == 1:
            Button(self,text="save delay",command=self.delayfunc1).pack()
        self.delayentry = self.delayent.get()   #self.delayentryvar.get()
        print(self.delayentry)

    def delayfunc1(self):
        self.delval = Text(self,height=1, width=10)
        self.delval.pack()
        self.delval.insert(END,self.delayentry)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    root = Tk()
    App(root)
    root.title("Delay Timer")
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is. Which part of this program does something unexpected?

Comment: Entry `self.delayent` is not returning the value, which I am storing in `self.delayentry` and at later point I would use this to appear on text field

Comment: It is returning the correct value. A newly created Entry is empty, so of course `self.delayent.get()` returns an empty string. It's not like you've given the user a chance to input any text, is it?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. *"What are the cases, that `StringVar()` / `IntVar()` would return blank / 0 value resp.?"*

First of all, by return, I have to assume you mean the return of the `get` method on them, because if not, the answer <strike>is *always* and *never*(they always return `None` and that is not equal to `0`)</strike> may vary respectively, as they ideally objects of the respective classes, or they fail to do so in which case I'd suspect they return `None`.

The cases for the both of `get` methods return the respective values are the same, they're either *never been set*(`''` and `0` are their default values) or they're *set explicitly to the default values*.

> 2. Below is my smaller part of code applied to one of the functionalities in my app. Please do tell me what am I missing in my code to retrieve the expected output.

It's not obvious to me what your expected output would be but I can point *some* of the aspects of the code that looks troublesome.

`self.delayvar` is instantiated exactly as it should be and is working correctly, whereas:

`self.delayentryvar` currently serves no purpose, it is *completely* redundant. That is mainly because `Entry` object already has a `get` method that works exactly the same way as that of `StringVar` object's, hence if that's the heart of needing `StringVar`, then it has *no use*.

```
self.delayent.get()
```

and:

```
self.delayentryvar.get()
```

are practically the same thing as explained above and in the code OP provided will *always* return `''`. That is because they're the returns of the *current* value of an `Entry` object that was first created almost an instant ago. The *Entry* isn't `insert`ed anything either, hence they return `None` or `''`.

Add:

```
self.delayent.insert('end', 'TEST')
```

inside `delayfunc` somewhere before:

```
self.delayentry = self.delayent.get()   #self.delayentryvar.get()
```

to have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Understanding your points. But I have seen in many tutorials that they explicitly create a `textvariable` before they create a `Entry` Why is that so

Comment: @cs2612 I don't know why they would do that, perhaps take a look at this question that I've asked: [When to use Variable classes? (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47334885/7032856)

Comment: @cs2612 it is likely they do this to prevent an error when creating the Entry field. If you have a text variable defined after the entry field is being created then you will get an error along the lines of `NameError: name 'variable_name' is not defined`