# how tk.DoubleVar() works?

Tags: python

hello guys i am working with a code that i cant understand:

```
current_value = tk.DoubleVar()

def get_current_value(): 
    return '{: .2f}'.format(current_value.get())

def brightness_changed(event):
    pct.set_brightness(get_current_value())

brightness = ttk.Scale(RHS,from_=0,to=100,orient='horizontal',
            command=brightness_changed,variable=current_value)
```

well, the last line is ok i made it myself, but the other is unknow for me, could you pleases simply tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Variable classes? (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334885/when-to-use-variable-classes-booleanvar-doublevar-intvar-stringvar)

Answer (score 0):

`DoubleVar()` is used for storing floats. In the code it is used by the Scale widget; each time you slide the scale the widget sets the `current_value` variable.

The widget also points to an event listener (using `command`) - a callback function that does something each time the slider moves or settles. As you can see this sets the brightness of `pct` - whatever that is - using the value in `current_value`. The function `get_current_value` seems a bit uneccesary, as the `event` parameter in `brightness_changed` contains the value of the slider.